# xcode : How to change view page with Flip effect on Button tap?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

**Below is the code of ModelController.m:**

```
- (id)init
{
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
    // Create the data model.
    DataHandler *handler = [DataHandler defaultDataHandler];
    [handler syncData];
    NSInteger tempTotal=1;//[[DataHandler defaultDataHandler] getTotalContents];
    NSMutableDictionary *favs=[Settings getSetting:kFavList];
    if(favs!=nil){
        tempTotal=[favs count]+1;
    }
    NSInteger TotalItems=tempTotal;//tempTotal>=6?tempTotal:6;
    NSInteger PageSize=6;

    NSInteger PageNo= (TotalItems/PageSize);
    if(TotalItems%PageSize!=0){
        PageNo++;
    }
    self.TotalPage=PageNo;
    NSInteger i=0,temp=PageSize;
    self.pageArray=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:PageNo];
    for (i=0; i<PageNo; i++) {
        temp=(PageNo==i+1 && TotalItems%PageSize!=0)? TotalItems%PageSize:PageSize;
        [self.pageArray setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",temp] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i+1]];
    }

    //NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    //_pageData = [[dateFormatter monthSymbols] copy];
    self.pageData=[self.pageArray allKeys];
}
 return self;
}

- (HomeViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {

NSLog(@"viewControllerAtIndex is called..");
// Return the data view controller for the given index.
if (([self.pageData count] == 0) || (index >= [self.pageData count])) {
    return nil;
}

// Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
HomeViewController *homeViewController = nil;
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    homeViewController = [[[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];
} else {
    homeViewController = [[[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController_iPad" bundle:nil] autorelease];
}

homeViewController.dataObject = [self.pageData objectAtIndex:index];
homeViewController.PageItemsCount= [[self.pageArray valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",index+1]] integerValue];
homeViewController.TotalPage=self.TotalPage;
homeViewController.CurrentPage=index+1;
return homeViewController;
}

- (NSUInteger)indexOfViewController:(HomeViewController *)viewController
{   
 // Return the index of the given data view controller.
 // For simplicity, this implementation uses a static array of model objects and the view controller stores the model object; you can therefore use the model object to identify the index.

return viewController.CurrentPage-1;
}
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
NSUInteger index = [self indexOfViewController:(HomeViewController *)viewController];
if ((index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound)) {
    return nil;
}

index--;
return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
NSUInteger index = [self indexOfViewController:(HomeViewController *)viewController];
if (index == NSNotFound) {
    return nil;
}

index++;
if (index == [self.pageData count]) {
    return nil;
}
return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}
```

This is working fine when I swipe the screen, **but I also want to change screen on any button tap of main view page** (in this case it's homeViewController.m), as it's code is very lengthy I didn't post code here.

can anyone tell me how to achieve this?

Thanks
Ashish

Comment: What does this have to do with Xcode?

Answer (score 1):

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"View Flip" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.80];
 [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

 [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight 
                           forView:self.view cache:NO];
 [UIView commitAnimations];
```

//Addd this line on click event of button action

Answer (score 0):

You could simply try and animate the view transform like this (for a vertical flip):

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^(void) {
                     view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1);
                 }
                 completion:nil];
```

Thanks